# How would I check if a directory is empty in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a CLI tool that avoids clobbering an existing directory with existing files but doesn't care if the directory doesn't exist or is empty.

I know I can use `.exists()` to see if the `PathBuf` points to an existing file/directory and `.is_dir()` to see if it is a directory, but how would I check to see if the directory is empty?

Comment: You list its contents.

Comment: Your concept is vulnerable to [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `.read_dir()` to get an iterator over the entries of the directory. `.` and `..` are skipped, so if the first `next()` call on the iterator returns `None` you know that the directory is empty.

```
let is_empty = dir_path_buf.read_dir()?.next().is_none();
```

If you are on Unix (POSIX, really) a different way to do this is to create a new temporary directory and try to rename it to the directory of the `PathBuf`. The `rename()` call, different from the `mv` utility, will rename a directory if the target is non-existent *or an empty directory*.

Comment: SO doesn't allow <6 char edits - I think it should be `read_dir()?.next().is_none()` yeah?

Answer (score 6):

One-liner to check if directory is readable and is empty:

```rust
PathBuf::from("t").read_dir().map(|mut i| i.next().is_none()).unwrap_or(false);
```